# How to avoid that a Bootstrap full screen modal with an image, closes with on click event

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm using full screen bootstrap modals, but I can't prevent that the modal closes with a click of the mouse in any part of the modal (I want that it only closes when clicking in the "close" button or the "x"). Is there any way to fix it without changing the bootstrap.js file?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="items-modal modal fade in" role="button" tabindex="-1" aria- hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
              &times;
            </button>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h2>H2</h2>
                    <img src="img/icon1.png" class="img-responsive img-centered" style="display:inline" alt=""></a>
                    <p>blablabla</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My custom.css:

```
.modal-content{
    height:100%;
}
.close{
    font-size: 200px;
    font-weight:300;
    margin-top:-30px;
}
.items-modal .modal-content{
    background-color:black;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

EDITED: I've tried defining `div id="myModal" class="items-modal modal fade in" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" role="button" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"`
but doesn't seem to work

Comment: Well that is not Bootstrap modal markup. Might want to compare and see that you have wrapped the modal inside a .close-modal class -- which is not in standard markup. Look at the docs

Comment: Thank you @Christina, you're right, without this wrapping it works as expected :)